# Action is dispatched correctly, but reducer doesn't get called

Tags: angular, firebase, ngrx

I dispatch a Login action and a Login Success action when it is successful.

Login actions triggers reducer correctly.
The success action doesn't trigger reducer when it has a payload (it triggers it if I remove the payload, but then I don't have the user).

But it does trigger a navigation effect correctly, and both actions are visible in the redux dev tools.

I get the following error from firebase on successful login (even tho I get the user back from the promise):

> core.js:6382 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
>       at Object.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.Firestore.configureClient (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120980:33)
>       at Object.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.Firestore.ensureClientConfigured (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120972:18)
>       at Object.get [as _isTerminated] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120926:18)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128600:37
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at freeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128590:40)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128603:17
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at freeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128590:40)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128603:17

Actions:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from 'firebase';

export const login = createAction('[Authentication/API] Login');
export const loginSuccess = createAction(
  '[Authentication/API] Login Success',
  props<{ user: User }>()
);
export const loginFail = createAction('[Authentication/API] Login Fail');
```

Effects:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { map, switchMap, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { navigate } from 'src/app/store/router';

import * as AuthenticationActions from './authentication.actions';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthenticationActions.login),
      switchMap(() =>
        from(this.authenticationService.login()).pipe(
          map(({ user }) => AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess({ user })),
          catchError(() => of(AuthenticationActions.loginFail()))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  navigateToDefaultPageOnSuccessfulLogin$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess),
      map(() => navigate({ url: 'transactions/import' }))
    )
  );
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as AuthenticationActions from './authentication.actions';
import { User } from 'firebase';

export interface AuthenticationState {
  user: User | null;
  isLoading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: AuthenticationState = {
  user: null,
  isLoading: false
};

export const authenticationReducer = createReducer<AuthenticationState>(
  initialState,
  on(AuthenticationActions.login, state => ({ ...state, isLoading: true })),
  on(AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess, (state, { user }) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    user
  })),
  on(AuthenticationActions.loginFail, state => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: false
  }))
);

export function reducer(
  state: AuthenticationState | undefined,
  action: Action
) {
  return authenticationReducer(state, action);
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  login() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
}
```

Comment: a stackblitz demo would be helpfull. Cheers chris

Comment: Will do next time. Right now I gave up, went without ngrx/store for authentication. I will get back to this after the more important features are done.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert `Promise` returned by `signInWithPopup` to an `Observable` :

```js
login(): Observable<any> {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  return from(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider));
}
```

I recommend you also to use a different approach to sign in and to retrieve current signed user :

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {

  check$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.check),
    switchMap(() => this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      map(user => user
        ? authActions.idAuthenticated({ user: user })
        : authActions.idNotAuthenticated()
      )
    ))
  ))

  login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.login),
    switchMap(() => this.authService.login().pipe(
      map(() => authActions.check()),
      catchError(error => of(authActions.authError({ message: 'Login failed' })))
    ))
  ))
```

auth.service.ts:

```
  login(): Observable<any> {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    return from(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider));
  }
}
```

with this architecture, you can dispatch `check` action when app is initialized. If user is already signed in, you will retrieve its credential.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(authActions.check());
}
```

If user is not already signed in, you will be able to navigate to an error page.

#### Note

Pay attention to your `navigateToDefaultPageOnSuccessfulLogin$` effect, you're invoking an incorrect method to navigate to url.

```js
  navigateToDefaultPageOnSuccessfulLogin$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess),
      map(() => this.router.navigate(['transactions/import' }))
    )
  );

  constructor(private router: Router, ...) {}
```